# how to get data within child key firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I am providing database structure image where parentId is unknown and child Id is known as shown in image.
how do I get all data inside this child Id lie date and contents of orders. I know code is wrong. But fetching just Order huge data and then comparing to this id will be not efficient.

```
let grabbedData = [];
firebase
      .database()
      .ref(`/orders/`) // or may be like this '/orders/CHILD/-MOzRqdxsBROTleyr1ct/'
      .child("-MOzRqdxsBROTleyr1ct")
      .on("value", (snapshot, key) => {
        console.log("snapshot....", snapshot);
        grabbedData.push(snapshot.val());
        
      });
```

[image: Database sturcture]

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to query on the key of a grandchild node in this structure. If you want to query order IDs, you will need to have a flat list of orders, instead of storing them under UIDs.

For example:

```
orders: {
  "-MP8B....PJ2": {
    uid: "EFTwvh....WZ2",
    date: ....,
    orders: ...
  },
  "-MPEB...bbf": {
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Now you can reach the order by their directly, and can still find the orders for a specific user by searching on the `uid` property.

Also see:

- [Firebase Query Double Nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested)
- [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value)